# Solidity: how to apply OR operator in function modifiers?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, access-modifiers

I have a contract with a private Enum `state` that has three options: `CREATED`, `VALID` and `TERMINATED`. This contract has a function `withdrawn` that can only be called by the contract creator, and a function `terminatine` that can only be called by a third-party that is set during the contract creation. Both functions have a modifier `requireState(State.VALID)` so they can only be called after the contract is in the `VALID` state.

The issue is that I want to configure the `withdrawn` function so it can be called if the `state` is set to `VALID` **OR** `TERMINATED`. How can I do that?

My `modifier` is shown below:

```
enum State { CREATED, VALID, TERMINATED }
State state;

modifier requireState(State _state) {
   require(state == _state);
   _;
}
```

I'm on Solidity 0.8.1.

Comment: The easiest solution: I suggest do not use a `modifier` but just have this condition at the beginning inside your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All modifiers of a function need to pass before this function is executed. So they always act as if they were connected by `AND` operators.

You can create a new modifier that accepts multiple values and performs an `OR` operation on them.

However, you'd need to either use a fixed amount of arguments or a fixed-length array, because Solidity currently doesn't allow one-line declaration of a dynamic length array.

Example: `[State.VALID, State.TERMINATED]` is declaration of a fixed-length array, so it doesn't match with `State[]` dynamic-length definition.

```
modifier requireAnyOfStates(State[2] memory _states) {
    require(_states[0] == state || _states[1] == state);
    _;
}
    
function foo() external requireAnyOfStates([State.VALID, State.TERMINATED]) {
}
```

But much simpler approach in this case is to just use a `require` statement in your function instead of a modifier.

```
function foo() external {
    require(state == State.VALID || state == State.TERMINATED);
}
```